# Persist State of Redux on Refresh in React.js

Tags: redux

> I am using redux in react.js When i refresh the application, redux state also get refreshed. How can I persist the redux state, without using the local storage.
>
> I don't want to know about redux-persist/redux-storage package

Answer (score 0):

In Main Class:

```
import PersistedStore from "./PersistedStore";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={PersistedStore.getDefaultStore().store}><MainClass />
  </Provider>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

add the following class to your project

```
import {
  createStore
} from "redux";

import rootreducer from './RootReducer'

const LOCAL_STORAGE_NAME = "localData";

class PersistedStore {

  // Singleton property
  static DefaultStore = null;

  // Accessor to the default instance of this class
  static getDefaultStore() {
    if (PersistedStore.DefaultStore === null) {
      PersistedStore.DefaultStore = new PersistedStore();
    }

    return PersistedStore.DefaultStore;
  }

  // Redux store
  _store = null;

  // When class instance is used, initialize the store
  constructor() {
    this.initStore()
  }

  // Initialization of Redux Store
  initStore() {
    this._store = createStore(rootReducer, PersistedStore.loadState());
    this._store.subscribe(() => {
      PersistedStore.saveState(this._store.getState());
    });
  }

  // Getter to access the Redux store
  get store() {
    return this._store;
  }

  // Loading persisted state from localStorage, no need to access
  // this method from the outside
  static loadState() {
    try {
      let serializedState = localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_NAME);

      if (serializedState === null) {
        return PersistedStore.initialState();
      }

      return JSON.parse(serializedState);
    } catch (err) {
      return PersistedStore.initialState();
    }
  }

  // Saving persisted state to localStorage every time something
  // changes in the Redux Store (This happens because of the subscribe() 
  // in the instore-method). No need to access this method from the outside
  static saveState(state) {
    try {
      let serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
      localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_NAME, serializedState);
    } catch (err) {}
  }

  // Return whatever you want your initial state to be
  static initialState() {
    return {};
  }
}

export default PersistedStore;
```